# Get error when load tfrecord file in tensorflow 2.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, wav, tfrecord

I'm trying to converting WAV files into TFRecord shards

In the code below, i use tf.audio.decode_wav to get an audio signal from wav file, label is an index list of sentence.

Then i save all wav file and label into train.tfrecord and split it

```
   def _write_tfrecord_file(self, shard_data):

        shard_path, indices = shard_data
        with tf.io.TFRecordWriter(shard_path, options='ZLIB') as out:
            for index in indices:
                file_path = self.data_dir + self.df['Filename'][index] + ".wav"
                label = str2index(self.df['Text'][index])

                raw_audio = tf.io.read_file(file_path)
                audio, sample_rate = tf.audio.decode_wav(
                    raw_audio,
                    desired_channels=1,  # mono
                    desired_samples=self.sample_rate * self.duration)

                example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={
                    'audio': _float_feature(audio.numpy().flatten().tolist()),
                    'label': _int64_feature(label)}))

                out.write(example.SerializeToString())
```

Then, i write a function to load

```
def _parse_batch(record_batch, sample_rate, duration):

    n_sample = sample_rate * duration

    feature_description = {
        'audio': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([n_sample], tf.float32),
        'label': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64)
    }

    example = tf.io.parse_example(record_batch, feature_description)

    return example['audio'], example['label']


def get_dataset_from_tfrecords(tfrecords_dir='tfrecords', split='train', batch_size=16, sample_rate=44100, duration=5,
                               n_epochs=10):
    if split not in ('train', 'validate'):
        raise ValueError("Split must be either 'train' or 'validate'")

    pattern = os.path.join(tfrecords_dir, '{}*.tfrecord'.format(split))

    files_ds = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(pattern)

    ignore_order = tf.data.Options()
    ignore_order.experimental_deterministic = False
    files_ds = files_ds.with_options(ignore_order)

    ds = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(files_ds, compression_type='ZLIB')

    ds.batch(batch_size)

    ds = ds.map(lambda x: _parse_batch(x, sample_rate, duration))

    if split == 'train':
        ds.repeat(n_epochs)

    return ds.prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)
```

But i get an error

```
ValueError: in converted code:

    D:\Natural Language Processing\speech_to_text\utils\load_tfrecord.py:38 None  *
        ds = ds.map(lambda x: _parse_batch(x, sample_rate, duration))
    D:\Natural Language Processing\speech_to_text\utils\load_tfrecord.py:16 _parse_batch  *
        example = tf.io.parse_example(record_batch, feature_description)
    C:\Users\levan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\parsing_ops.py:807 parse_example_v2
        dense_types, dense_defaults, dense_shapes, name)
    C:\Users\levan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\parsing_ops.py:868 _parse_example_raw
        name=name)
    C:\Users\levan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\gen_parsing_ops.py:626 parse_example
        name=name)
    C:\Users\levan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\op_def_library.py:793 _apply_op_helper
        op_def=op_def)
    C:\Users\levan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\func_graph.py:548 create_op
        compute_device)
    C:\Users\levan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\ops.py:3429 _create_op_internal
        op_def=op_def)
    C:\Users\levan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\ops.py:1773 __init__
        control_input_ops)
    C:\Users\levan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\ops.py:1613 _create_c_op
        raise ValueError(str(e))

    ValueError: Shape must be rank 1 but is rank 0 for 'ParseExample/ParseExample' (op: 'ParseExample') with input shapes: [], [0], [], [], [], [].
```

How can i fix this?

Comment: Do some samples don't have any label or something? From the stacktrace which show `[], [0], [], [], [], []`. Try put numbers to those empty list.

Comment: It still error, :(( huhu. Length of label does not equal, is that a problem?

Comment: Yeah, label and sample must be the same length.

Comment: Oh, how can i convert sentences which have a different length into index list of the same length?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error occurs when the shape passed to `ParseExample` doesn't match between serialized Example and features description.

I was able to reproduce your error using the below code where the shape between the `serialized_tf_example` and `feature_configs` don't match thus throws the error.

**Code to reproduce the error -**

```
import tensorflow as tf
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
serialized_tf_example = tf.placeholder(tf.string, shape=[], name='serialized_tf_example')
feature_configs = {'x': tf.FixedLenFeature(shape=[1], dtype=tf.float32)}
tf_example = tf.parse_example(serialized_tf_example, feature_configs)

feature_dict = {'x': tf.train.Feature(float_list=tf.train.FloatList(value=[25]))}
example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature=feature_dict))
f = example.SerializeToString()


sess.run(tf_example,feed_dict={serialized_tf_example:[f]})
```

**Output -**

```
/tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py:1750: UserWarning: An interactive session is already active. This can cause out-of-memory errors in some cases. You must explicitly call `InteractiveSession.close()` to release resources held by the other session(s).
  warnings.warn('An interactive session is already active. This can '
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
/tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py in _create_c_op(graph, node_def, inputs, control_inputs)
   1606   try:
-> 1607     c_op = c_api.TF_FinishOperation(op_desc)
   1608   except errors.InvalidArgumentError as e:

InvalidArgumentError: Shape must be rank 1 but is rank 0 for 'ParseExample_16/ParseExample' (op: 'ParseExample') with input shapes: [], [0], [], [0].
```

Another example, the error also appears when the input type expected and the data passed are also different. For example if I modify `tf_example = tf.parse_example([serialized_tf_example], feature_configs)` then we get `InvalidArgumentError: Shape must be rank 1 but is rank 2 for 'ParseExample_21/ParseExample' (op: 'ParseExample')` error as expected.

The error was fixed when we passed proper shape to both `serialized_tf_example` and `feature_configs`.

**Fixed Code -**

```
import tensorflow as tf
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
serialized_tf_example = tf.placeholder(tf.string, shape=[1], name='serialized_tf_example')
feature_configs = {'x': tf.FixedLenFeature(shape=[1], dtype=tf.float32)}
tf_example = tf.parse_example(serialized_tf_example, feature_configs)

feature_dict = {'x': tf.train.Feature(float_list=tf.train.FloatList(value=[25]))}
example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature=feature_dict))
f = example.SerializeToString()


sess.run(tf_example,feed_dict={serialized_tf_example:[f]})
```

**Output -**

```
{'x': array([[25.]], dtype=float32)}
```

Hope this answers your question. Happy Learning.

Comment: @levanpon - Hope we have answered your question. Can you please accept and upvote the answer if you are satisfied with the answer.